# Trying to bind submit and save to localStorage

Tags: reactjs

Here my App.js code, I am trying to bind and capture the "handlesubmit" function, and then append to an empty list which will be populated. Thanks.

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [songs, setSongs] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('songs');
    if (!data) { }
    setSongs(JSON.parse(data));
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('songs', JSON.stringify(songs));
  });

  const handleSubmit = data => {
    setSongs([data]);
  }

  return (
    <main>
    <h1>Music Editor</h1>

    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))} autoComplete="false">
      <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Type title/name of song" value="" />
      <input type="submit" value="Add song" />
    </form>

    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the problem you're having? What isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is commented in the code itself.
Here is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-banzai-2byw1?file=/src/App.js:0-1202) to see the App working.

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [songs, setSongs] = React.useState([]);

  // use another state for song title
  const [songTitle, setSongTitle] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('songs');
    // only update the state when the data persists
    if (data) setSongs(JSON.parse(data));
  }, []);

  // update the localStorage whenever the songs array changes
  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('songs', JSON.stringify(songs));
  }, [songs]);

  // inside the functional component, there is no "this" keyword
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // append the new song title with the old one
    setSongs([
      ...songs,
      songTitle
    ]);
  }

  return (
    <main>
    <h1>Music Editor</h1>

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete="false">
      <label htmlFor="title">Title:</label>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        id="title" 
        name="title" 
        placeholder="Type title/name of song" 
        value={songTitle}
        onChange={e => setSongTitle(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Add song" />
    </form>

    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: ["C","o","l","d","P","l","a","y"," ","-"," ","L","o","s","t"] ??

Comment: @JohnSmith My bad. You need not spread the songTitle since it is a string here in line while updating the state. 

    **setSongs([ ...songs, songTitle ])**
 
I have made change the code also.

Comment: Please explain, I do not understand.

Comment: @JohnSmith While submitting the song title, we should append the new `songTitle` to the previous ones in `songs`. So, in order to do that, we could simply do **setSongs([ ...songs, songTitle ])** which means we are updating the songs array with the new song title. For convenience, you should clear our the localStorage and check again.